# CakePHP radio button class to have array data

Tags: php, cakephp

So in CakePHP, I am setting up some options. In the options I am trying to get the class attribute to look something like this:

```
class='application_level_#'
```

The # comes from data inside the $app_list. The $app_list looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [Nature] => 5 ),
[1] => Array ( [Math] => 0 ), 
[2] => Array ( [Art] => 0 ) )
```

The elements correspond to each school which has a name is the key and the value is the application level. This value is what the # should be. I have users selecting a grade which fires a function and retrieves the value of the grade. Then in my function I am changing css for the display of the school selection to block (from none) and then changing each school radio element with the class='application_level_#' to display: block (from none) using Javascript.

My school_form_element.ctp:

```
<!-- Schools Element -->
<div id="school_selection"> 
    <?php
        $schools = $this->requestAction('/schools/index');
        $app_list = $this->requestAction('/schools/app_list');

        print_r($app_list);

        //Sets up a radio button. 
        echo $this->Form->input('school_selection', 
            array('type' => 'radio', 'options' => $schools, 'onclick' => 'showStudentInfoBox()', 'class' => '**app_list[id]** how to build this?'));
    ?>
</div>
<!-- End Schools Element -->
```

Javascript (form.js)

```
function showSchools(){
    var grade_radio = document.getElementsByName('data[StudentApplicationForms][grade_selection]');
    var application_level = null;

    for(var i=0, length = grade_radio.length; i < length; i++){
        if(grade_radio[i].checked){
            application_level = grade_radio[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    var school_options = document.getElementsByClassName('application_level_', application_level);
    school_options.style.display = 'block';

}
```

EDIT: Should I be looking at the JS helper of CakePHP?

Comment: I don't think this is possible using a single radio input.  I'm not sure on this, but you may be able to break them up into multiple radio inputs and get the effect you want though.

Comment: I've never seen `class="app_list[id]"` written like you would would on `name` for a collection of elements, It would be done like `class="app_list-1"`, `class="app_list-2"` etc... Also, Typically a `class` applies to multiple elements, otherwise you would just make use of their unique IDs.

Comment: @ficuscr Ya, the class='app_list-0' will belong to a set of schools that I want to display.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to get the class="app_list[id][any key aka school name][application_level]" the key (school name) points to the value (application_level) that determines which schools to show. EDIT: As in my example array, the id points to the school and their application level. The Math and Nature school have the same application_level value and I want that to be appended in class tag.

Comment: Cake's form helper is only useful so far, once you start needing to do even remotely complex tasks, it's often easier to just do certain elements by hand.

Comment: just out of curiosity @pmac89, if you happen to have 100 records that means you will have 100 classes?